Jasper Reports - How to prevent printing empty page
Jaspersoft Studio 6.20.0
Server 7.8.0
I have a Report with two subreports. The first one can take dynamic hight of the page.
The second one is this:
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TEST_NOTIZEN" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoPages" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="110febd2-dc25-46dd-b70c-f48ad6824150">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="XXXX"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select tabelle from appcode where tabelle < 10]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="17" uuid="85bcb0de-4334-4825-832d-a703a61882d4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Datum ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="80" y="0" width="1" height="17" uuid="7b654a9c-f3c9-4e2a-9c4e-a6a803a9ff60">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="17" uuid="8db2b19c-86f1-4852-bf2c-dd7e3d6e7ec1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="80" y="0" width="1" height="17" uuid="2482ede8-86aa-4495-af09-d3e2fccfaedc">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>

My goal is to fill the remaining space of the page, to get a grid where people can make some notes by hand, like in this Picture:
Report
To achiev this, the print when expression is set to $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1
This works fine and the textfields/the grid is only printed on page 1, but at the end, it always prints an additional empty page (as you can see in the image above, there's a 2nd page which should not be there). If i put a page- or rowheader or footer these are printet on the empty page. But the additional page is also printed if there's only the detail band.
The SQL query ist just a "pseudo" query which gives me enough rows to fill a whole page (first report can also be empty) .
I experimented for hours with all the properties but I couldn't figure out how to get rid of that empty page.
What I have also tried is to put a Grid in de background band and set runToBottom="true". But the background is not printed if it is in a subreport...!?
Thanks in advance!
